# SELECT - filter out results that meet criteria

Tags: mysql

I have two relational tables. From them, I'd like to work out a SELECT query that retrieves items that "fall in between" values in the columns.

I'm new to MySQL and queries of the kind isn't my strong side. I'm certain I'm looking at the problem from the wrong angle. Hopefully, I could get some foothold from here!

Ok, here goes: I have two tables: *products* and *line_items* where *product_id* is the primary key for the first with a one to many relationships with the matching field in the latter. The tables hold the following columns:

**products**

```
product_id
```

**line_items**

```
product_id
timestamp_out
timestamp_in
```

The time stamps indicate when a product has been taken out (out) of stock and when it has been re-inserted into stock again (in). The same *product_id* can appear multiple times in *line_items* and *timestamp_out* is always less than *timestamp_in*.

What I'd like to do is to retrieve *product_id*s for when a product is not "checked out".

E.g. *product_id* 1, might have the following rows in *line_items*:

**first row**

```
-timestamp_out: 1
-timestamp_in: 3
```

**second row**

```
-timestamp_out: 6
-timestamp_in: 7
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a query that would take two arbitrary time stamps and return the products that are not checked out between those time stamps (e.g. if the timestamps in a query were out: 4 and in: 6, then product_id 1 should not be returned, since the upper spectrum of that span crosses over with the time span of *second row*; only if the timestamps in the query are out: 4 and in: 5, or above 7 should *product_id* 1 be returned).

I've tried several variations of the queries, but the one I suppose is the "closest" would be:

```
SELECT
    products.product_id
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN
    line_items
ON
    (products.product_id = line_items.product_id)
WHERE
    6 NOT BETWEEN line_items.timestamp_out AND timestamp_in
OR 
    4 NOT BETWEEN line_items.timestamp_out AND timestamp_in
```

This doesn't work though since it returns *product_id* 1 seeing how the condition is true for the first row. If I reverse it to:

```
WHERE
    6 BETWEEN line_items.timestamp_out AND timestamp_in
OR 
    4 BETWEEN line_items.timestamp_out AND timestamp_in
```

...this will of course also return *product_id* 1 as the span in the query crosses over with the span of the second row.

Hope I'm making the problem clear! I must confess I feel a little bit queasy from looking at this for the past couple of hours without being able to wrap my head around how to do these kinds of MySQL queries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the timestamps that define the range you want to query `query_start` and `query_end`.

The timestamp range in a `line_items` row *does not* overlap with the query range if either `query_end < timestamp_out` (the query range ended before the product was taken out of stock) or `query_start > timestamp_in` (the query range started after the product was returned to stock).

We're looking for a product where all of the `line_item` rows for that product do not overlap with the range--or alternately, where there does not exist a row that does overlap.

```
select *
from product p
where not exists (
    select *
    from line_items i
    where i.product_id = p.product_id
    and not (@query_end < i.timestamp_out or @query_start > i.timestamp_in)
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works like a charm! I'd give you a +1 but I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that should work for your use case.

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from line_items l
    where 
        l.product_id = p.product_id
        AND NOT (
               l.timestamp_in  < @out
            OR l.timestamp_out > @in
        )
  );
```

For each product, the query ensures that there is no record in `line_items` that overlaps the given interval.

I tested it with your sample data **[in this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3p2USu4qy8ki39MLmiSZhM/1)** and it seems to match your expected results, ie :

- `@out=4, @in=6` : no results
- `@out=4, @in=5` : product 1 selected
- `@out=8, @in=9` : product 1 selected

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm, Willis Blackburn came with the same answer just a minute before, thanks a lot still!